# How can I speed up my approximate natural log function?

Tags: optimization, rust, natural-logarithm

I have implemented an approximate natural log function based on a **Padé Approximation** of a truncated Taylor Series. The accuracy is acceptable (±0.000025) but despite several rounds of optimizations, its exec time is still about 2.5x that of the standard library `ln` function! If it isn't faster and it isn't as accurate, it is worthless! Nevertheless, I am using this as a way to learn how to optimize my Rust code. (My timings come from using the `criterion` crate. I used blackbox, summed the values in the loop and created a string from the result to defeat the optimizer.)

On Rust Playground, my code is:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=94246553cd7cc0c7a540dcbeff3667b9

### Algorithm

An overview of my algorithm, which works on a ratio of unsigned integers:

1. Range reduction to the interval [1, 2] by dividing by the largest power of two not exceeding the value:

   - Change representation of numerator   → `2ⁿ·N where 1 ≤ N ≤ 2`
   - Change representation of denominator → `2ᵈ·D where 1 ≤ D ≤ 2`
2. This makes the result `log(numerator/denominator) = log(2ⁿ·N / 2ᵈ·D) = (n-d)·log(2) + log(N) - log(D)`
3. To perform log(N), Taylor series does not converge in the neighborhood of zero, but it does near one...
4. ... since N is near one, substitute x = N - 1 so that we now need to evaluate log(1 + x)
5. Perform a substitution of `y = x/(2+x)`
6. Consider the related function `f(y) = Log((1+y)/(1-y))`

   - `= Log((1 + x/(2+x)) / (1 - x/(2+x)))`
   - `= Log( (2+2x) / 2)`
   - `= Log(1 + x)`
7. f(y) has a Taylor Expansion which converges must faster than the expansion for Log(1+x) ...

   - For Log(1+x) → `x - x²/2 + x³/3 - y⁴/4 + ...`
   - For Log((1+y)/(1-y)) → `y + y³/3 + y⁵/5 + ...`
8. Use the Padé Approximation for the truncated series `y + y³/3 + y⁵/5 ...`
9. ... Which is `2y·(15 - 4y²)/(15 - 9y²)`
10. Repeat for the denominator and combine the results.

### Padé Approximation

Here is the Padé Approximation part of the code:

```rust
/// Approximate the natural logarithm of one plus a number in the range (0..1). 
/// 
/// Use a Padé Approximation for the truncated Taylor series for Log((1+y)/(1-y)).
/// 
///   - x - must be a value between zero and one, inclusive.
#[inline]
fn log_1_plus_x(x : f64) -> f64 {
    // This is private and its caller already checks for negatives, so no need to check again here. 
    // Also, though ln(1 + 0) == 0 is an easy case, it is not so much more likely to be the argument
    // than other values, so no need for a special test.
    let y = x / (2.0 + x);
    let y_squared = y * y;
    // Original Formula is this: 2y·(15 - 4y²)/(15 - 9y²)
    // 2.0 * y * (15.0 - 4.0 * y_squared) / (15.0 - 9.0 * y_squared)

    // Reduce multiplications: (8/9)y·(3.75 - y²)/((5/3) - y²)
    0.8888888888888889 * y * (3.75 - y_squared) / (1.6666666666666667 - y_squared)
}
```

Clearly, not much more to speed up there!

### Most Significant Bit

The change that has had the most impact so far was optmizing my calculation that gets the position of the **most significant bit**. I need that for the range reduction.

Here is my `msb` function:

````rust
/// Provide `msb` method for numeric types to obtain the zero-based
/// position of the most significant bit set.
/// 
/// Algorithms used based on this article: 
/// https://prismoskills.appspot.com/lessons/Bitwise_Operators/Find_position_of_MSB.jsp
pub trait MostSignificantBit {
    /// Get the zero-based position of the most significant bit of an integer type.
    /// If the number is zero, return zero. 
    /// 
    /// ## Examples: 
    /// 
    /// ```
    ///    use clusterphobia::clustering::msb::MostSignificantBit;
    /// 
    ///    assert!(0_u64.msb() == 0);
    ///    assert!(1_u64.msb() == 0);
    ///    assert!(2_u64.msb() == 1);
    ///    assert!(3_u64.msb() == 1);
    ///    assert!(4_u64.msb() == 2);
    ///    assert!(255_u64.msb() == 7);
    ///    assert!(1023_u64.msb() == 9);
    /// ```
    fn msb(self) -> usize;
}

#[inline]
/// Return whether floor(log2(x))!=floor(log2(y))
/// with zero for false and 1 for true, because this came from C!
fn ld_neq(x : u64, y : u64) -> u64 {
    let neq = (x^y) > (x&y);
    if neq { 1 } else { 0 }
}

impl MostSignificantBit for u64 {
    #[inline]
    fn msb(self) -> usize {
        /*
        // SLOWER CODE THAT I REPLACED:
        // Bisection guarantees performance of O(Log B) where B is number of bits in integer.
        let mut high = 63_usize;
        let mut low = 0_usize;
        while (high - low) > 1
        {
            let mid = (high+low)/2;
            let mask_high = (1 << high) - (1 << mid);
            if (mask_high & self) != 0 { low = mid; }
            else { high = mid; }
        }
        low
        */

        // This algorithm found on pg 16 of "Matters Computational" at  https://www.jjj.de/fxt/fxtbook.pdf
        // It avoids most if-branches and has no looping.
        // Using this instead of Bisection and looping shaved off 1/3 of the time.
        const MU0 : u64 = 0x5555555555555555; // MU0 == ((-1UL)/3UL) == ...01010101_2
        const MU1 : u64 = 0x3333333333333333; // MU1 == ((-1UL)/5UL) == ...00110011_2
        const MU2 : u64 = 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f; // MU2 == ((-1UL)/17UL) == ...00001111_2
        const MU3 : u64 = 0x00ff00ff00ff00ff; // MU3 == ((-1UL)/257UL) == (8 ones)
        const MU4 : u64 = 0x0000ffff0000ffff; // MU4 == ((-1UL)/65537UL) == (16 ones)
        const MU5 : u64 = 0x00000000ffffffff; // MU5 == ((-1UL)/4294967297UL) == (32 ones)
        let r : u64 = ld_neq(self, self & MU0)
        + (ld_neq(self, self & MU1) << 1)
        + (ld_neq(self, self & MU2) << 2)
        + (ld_neq(self, self & MU3) << 3)
        + (ld_neq(self, self & MU4) << 4)
        + (ld_neq(self, self & MU5) << 5);
        r as usize
    }
}
````

### Rust u64::next_power_of_two, unsafe code and intrinsics

Now I know that Rust has a fast method for finding the lowest power of two greater than or equal to a number. I need this, but I also need the bit position, because that is the equivalent of the log base 2 of my numbers. (For example: next_power_of_two(255) yields 256, but I want 8, because it has the 8th bit set.) Looking at the source code for `next_power_of_two`, I see this line inside a private helper method called `fn one_less_than_next_power_of_two`:

```rust
    let z = unsafe { intrinsics::ctlz_nonzero(p) };
```

So is there an **intrinsic** that I can use to get the bit position the same way? Is it used in a public method that I have access to? Or is there a way to write unsafe code to call some intrinsic I don't know about (which is most of them)?

If there is such a methd or intrinsic I can call, I suspect that will greatly speed up my program, but maybe there are other things that will also help.

**UPDATE:**

Head smack! I can use `63 - x.leading_zeros()` to find the position of the most significant bit! I just didn't think of coming from the other end. I will try this and see if it speeds things up...

Comment: Production transcendental impls use fancy tricks for speed: Polynomial approximations, specialized instructions (often coded in assembly tuned to a specific processor even among a family like x86, etc.).  Careful analysis and corrective math are needed to get the lowest order bits right for all possible inputs. So a quick, straightforward implementation is probably not going to compete very well. In case useful, there's a C-only impl here: http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_log.c . You can download the glibc source to see processor-specific versions.

Comment: @Gene - Over the last two days, that has began to dawn on me! Ah, the Hubris of thinking I can out-log the system lumberjacks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single optimization cut the time in half!

I rewrote my msb (most significant bit) function to use the library function `u64::leading_zeroes` that internally uses intrinsics:

```rust
    fn msb(self) -> usize {
        // THIRD ATTEMPT
        let z = self.leading_zeros();
        if z == 64 { 0 }
        else { 63 - z as usize }
    }
```

Now my log approximation only takes 6% longer than the intrinsic ln function. I am unlikely to do much better.

Lesson learned: Use the builtin log!

**UPDATE:**

The above worked for my use case, but if you want a general purpose log(x) function that works over this range: [1,e=2.718281828], I came up with this for a later project:

I finally settled on using a third-order Padé Approximant, which was accurate enough for my range of x ∈ [1,2]. In release mode, it is about twice as fast as the system log.

```rust
    fn pade_approximant_log(x: f64, log_base : f64) -> f64 {
        let x2 = x * x;
        let x3 = x2 * x;

        // 2nd order: 
        // let numerator = 3.0 * (x2 - 1.0);
        // let denominator = log_base * (x2 + 4.0*x + 1.0);

        // 3rd order: 
        let numerator = (11.0/27.0) * x3 + x2 - x - (11.0/27.0);
        let denominator = log_base * (x3/9.0 + x2 + x + (1.0/9.0));

        let ln_x = numerator / denominator;
        ln_x
    }
```

To get the Pade Approximant, I went to Wolfram Alpha and ran this:

```
PadeApproximant(ln[x], {x, 1, {3, 3}})
```

Then I rewrote the polynomial that it gave me to use fewer multiplications.
In the above, note that I have the caller pass in the natural log of their number base as a precomputed value. I use the same base in all my calls, so this removes the need for a log call in my main loops. Thus the above works for any number base.